# What does this comparison of hexadecimal (If ((&H7F And &H80) = &H80)) means ?

Tags: vb.net, compare, hex

I got This code from a free source

```
  Private Sub SetFields(ByRef FieldByte As Byte)
    If ((FieldByte And &H80) = &H80) Then
        FieldTime = True
    Else
        FieldTime = False
    End If
    If ((FieldByte And &H40) = &H40) Then
        FieldOpenInterest = True
    Else
        FieldOpenInterest = False
    End If
    If ((FieldByte And &H20) = &H20) Then
        FieldOpenPrice = True
    Else
        FieldOpenPrice = False
    End If
    If ((FieldByte And &H10) = &H10) Then 'Not sure which is high or low
        FieldHigh = True
    Else
        FieldHigh = False
    End If
    If ((FieldByte And &H8) = &H8) Then 'Not sure which is high or low
        FieldLow = True
    Else
        FieldLow = False
    End If
End Sub
```

the value of FieldByte sent is &H7F, this value is enablig all fields except FieldTime

What should be the value of FieldByte in order to enable All fields? and can anybody explain what does this comparison means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base 16 value &H7F is equivalent to 01111111 in base 2.
The base 16 value &H80 is equivalent to 10000000 in base 2.

so for the bitwise operation

```
0111111 AND    (&H7F)
1000000 =      (&H80) 
------------
0000000
```

the result is zero and your FieldTime is set to False.

Any other value less than &H80 when used with the bitwise operator AND against &H7F will always return the same value

For example

```
0111111 AND   (&H7F)
0100000 =     (&H40)  
-------
0100000       (&H40)
```

You could find a more detailed article on [BitWise operators in VB.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V#divTab2VBNET) here

To enable all fields you need to set your FieldByte variable to &HFF so

```
1111111 AND    (&HFF)
1000000 =      (&H80) 
------------
1000000        (&H80)
```

Comment: I'd say &HF8 sets all the flags checked... FF would set 1-2-4 too

Comment: Following the logic here `If ((FieldByte And &H80) = &H80) Then`

Comment: Yeah but you don't know what the bits 1-2-4 are used for... maybe in some other function and you don't want to touch these by accident

Comment: Still a great explaination of what this is about =)

Comment: I am the last one to contend your approach. You have my full agreement with your implementation, however the code above doesn't touch these bits and my answer was  primarily an effort to explain _and can anybody explain what does this comparison means_

Comment: Did not mean to offend you or anything, just wanted to say that &HF8 would set all the bits checked... &HFF does it too + sets bits 1-2-4 which may and only may lead to other problems when reusing the resulting value

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you could implement an enum with flags attribute to get way less cryptic code:

```
Module Demo

    Dim FieldTime As Boolean
    Dim FieldOpenInterest As Boolean
    Dim FieldOpenPrice As Boolean
    Dim FieldHigh As Boolean
    Dim FieldLow As Boolean

    Sub Main()
        'SetFields(&HFF) ' would set all flags as mentioned in the other answer,
                         ' however all of them not only the ones specified
        SetFields(FieldInfo.FieldTime Or _
                  FieldInfo.FieldOpenInterest Or _
                  FieldInfo.FieldOpenPrice Or _
                  FieldInfo.FieldOpenPrice Or _
                  FieldInfo.FieldHigh Or _
                  FieldInfo.FieldLow) 'same thing but less cryptic and you dont have to think about what you do so much
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetFields(ByRef FieldByte As FieldInfo)
        FieldTime = (FieldByte And FieldInfo.FieldTime) = FieldInfo.FieldTime
        FieldOpenInterest = (FieldByte And FieldInfo.FieldOpenInterest) = FieldInfo.FieldOpenInterest
        FieldOpenPrice = (FieldByte And FieldInfo.FieldOpenPrice) = FieldInfo.FieldOpenPrice
        FieldHigh = (FieldByte And FieldInfo.FieldHigh) = FieldInfo.FieldHigh
        FieldLow = (FieldByte And FieldInfo.FieldLow) = FieldInfo.FieldLow
    End Sub

    <Flags()>
    Private Enum FieldInfo ' hope i got the calculations right =P
        FieldHigh = 16
        FieldTime = 128
        FieldOpenPrice = 32
        FieldOpenInterest = 64
        FieldLow = 8
    End Enum

End Module
```

Comment: @user3471633 The implementation of SetFields is a bit weird ... if something = somethingelse then this is true else this is false ... you can assign the output of the comparison directly to the boolean field

Comment: Great Implementation Florian . it is more dynamic .

Comment: @user3471633 and more readable... the most important thing when programming the big stuff...

Comment: @user3471633 to get the proper values of the enum use calc.exe and change the view to programmer... enter the hex value in hex mode and switch to dec mode ... 80 becomes 128, etc...

Comment: @user3471633 and you still can call the method using a byte even if the signature has an enum as parameter...